# TYPO3: Backend Usability when using Bootstrap and Grid Elements

Tags: typo3, fluid, usability

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but I figured I might as well try to get an answer here.

My problem is the following: I'm a huge fan of Bootstrap and all there components so I'm genreally using them in every project im working on. So when I'm using `container` and `container-fluid` with different `row`'s in between for sertain content-elements I haven't figured out a way to implement this inside the backend in an user-friendly way.

The way I used to do it was simply use the [Grid Elements Extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/gridelements/) to simply create `containers`, `row`'s and `col`'s and implement those within each other in the backend. Works fine, but its a whole lot of work for the user of the site to create content. I don't know if my explenation was clear, english isn't my first language and I don't know how to describe it in another way, but here's a picture of what I'm trying to say:

[image: Screenshot of an installation]

As you can see there are a lot of elements nested within each other so the user or admin has to actually "know" how bootstrap works to edit content without destroying the layout.

Is there any other way I can achive full flexibility for the content, e.g.  a bunch of `container`'s within a `container-fluid` as a wrapper and another bunch of `cols`'s as children of the `container`?

I've tried to work with [Mask](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask/), which seemed to be the solution at the beginning, but in the end I had to create one mask object for every possible way an element could be loaded, so there goes this option..

Does anyone else have this kind of "problem" or is there a simple (or hard, idc) solution I can use?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Do you use bootstrap_package extension?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your "problem". My opinion: As soon as you have a page layout with multiple containers (container / container-fluid) and a flexible grid layout, I guess there is no better way without restricting flexibility or have some dirty logic / code. In some (minor) cases, you can help yourself with layout classes (DB field "layout") and some logic in fluid + a viewhelper to calculate the grid columns (e.g. imagegallery, where you can set the columns in backend and calculate the columns in frontend). But in my opinion, this is the most flexible way.

There are some people who solve this with new content elements and inline relation to its content elements. But IMHO this is more confusing for editors to see a grid layout in the backend and the possibility to flexible add content elements via content element to the container / column of choice.

A small, but effective useful helper for editors is to colorize your grid elements in the backend to help the editor to recognize different grids.

In my experience, editors can handle nested grids better than searching for multiple dropdowns in elements to understand grids.

Offtopic: editors survived templavoila, they will understand grids :-)